# Get a string from resource file

Tags: wpf, vb.net, resourcedictionary

I looked at this sample :

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article811-simplest-way-to-implement-multilingual-wpf-application.aspx

However, this sample shows how to get strings into the GUI.

How do I get a string into a variable.

I want to display a messagebox , with a string from the resource file.

Thanks in advance
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you use the [`ResourceDictionary.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms601221%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) this is the example code modified to make it do what you want it to.

```
Class MainWindow
    Dim dict As ResourceDictionary = New ResourceDictionary()
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        SetLanguageDictionary()
        MessageBox.Show(dict.Item("greeting").ToString)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetLanguageDictionary()

        Select Case (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
            Case "en-US"
                dict.Source = New Uri("..\Resources\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
            Case "fr-CA"
                dict.Source = New Uri("..\Resources\StringResources.fr-CA.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
            Case Else
                dict.Source = New Uri("..\Resources\StringResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the ResourceFile I was using

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:system ="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" >        
    <system:String x:Key="greeting">Hello World</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Its working!!!
I was missing a .item(0).item code... :
S = Me.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Item(0).Item("login").ToString
Thank you!!!